# Exporting Redux Store Fails Enzyme Tests

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using the [duck pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) and [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to set up a redux store like this:

```
store/index.js

/* import staments */

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const ducks = {
  auth,
  password,
  navbar,
  tasks,
};

const reducer = ducksReducer(ducks);

const middleware = applyMiddleware(ducksMiddleware(reducer));

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeWithDevTools(middleware));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

The app runs fine and all tests pass, but when I export the `store` variable (trying to dispatch an action) in a utility non-React file, the test will break.

```
utils/http.js

// Commenting this line will make things work perfectly fine
import { store } from '../store'; /

import { stopSession } from '../store/modules/session';

...

const handleResponse = (response, onSuccess, onFail) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return onSuccess();
  }
  // 401 Unauthorized when session expires.
  if (response.status === 401) {
    response.text().then(message => store.dispatch(stopSession(message)));
  }
  return onFail();
};
...
```

All the reducers have initial states that are not undefined, all the `switch` statements have default return values. The app works perfectly fine, just the tests do not like the store to be exported and used like this.

**Updated**: here's a stripped down `auth` reducer:
**NOTE:** not only `auth` reducer is breaking, every reducer is.

```
import http from '../../utils/http';

// Actions
export const LOGIN_RESET = 'LOGIN_RESET';
// ... more actions

// Actions creators
export const login = (email, password) => ({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST, email, password });
// ... more action creators


// Selectors
export const loginLoading = ({ auth }) => auth.loginStatus === 'loading';
export const getUser = ({ auth }) => auth.user;
// ... more selectors

const initialState = {
  loginStatus: null,
  signupStatus: null,
  signupErrors: [],
  logoutStatus: null,
  userLoggedIn: false,
  user: {},
};

export default function reduce(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_RESET:
      return {
        ...state,
        loginStatus: null,
      };
    // ... more cases
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Middleware
export const middleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => async (action) => {
  next(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST: {
      const { email, password } = action;
      const response = await http.post('users/sign_in', {
        user: { email, password },
      });
      http.handleResponse(
        response,
        async () => {
          const user = await response.json();
          return dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            user,
          });
        },
        () => dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE })
      );
      break;
    }
    // ... more cases
  return null;
};
```

Here is the screenshot of the tests running:

[image: Enzyme tests fail]

Honestly, I don't see anything wrong with the reducers or the store setup. This could be something to do with enzyme itself, when it tries to render the app from an `undefined` store. If I remove the import statement in `http.js`, things work just fine.

Comment: Can you post `auth` reducer please?

Comment: Make sure you're exporting your auth reducer correctly, as well as importing it correctly.

Comment: I’m afk now. Will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Please share the code of store.js

Comment: @Volodymyr the first code block is the `store/index.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's nothing wrong with store setup or the reducers. I was able to solve the issue by creating a mock `http.js` file to make Enzyme happy.

So in the root-level config `index.js` (in `__test__` folder), tell jest to initialize a mock from a file:

```
/* /src/__tests__/index.js */

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.mock('../utils/http.js');
```

And in the same location of `http.js` file, add a mock file (must be inside `__mocks__`)

```
/* /src/utils/__mocks__/http.js */

const http = {};
export default http;
```

The problem is when running the tests, Enzyme loads `http.js` and at that point, the store is not set up yet. Perhaps I should not dispatch actions in a http helper, a better way of doing this would be having a middleware. I'm not sure if this solution is a good practice, so any comment/ suggestion is welcomed.